# How to get Google Docs into dark mode when the browser's forced dark flag is enabled?

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge, google-docs, darkmode

I have been using the `#enable-force-dark` flag (found under `edge://flags` for Microsoft Edge) for a while, and all websites, including Google Docs, were working perfectly fine then—but ever since Google Docs updated something about how document  pages, and their color, are setup this past month I can't get documents to  darken (regardless of which drop-down `edge://flags/#enable-force-dark` selection is made), even if I change the page color to dark on Google Docs. Any workarounds within the website itself,  Microsoft Edge, and/or another browser?

Note: if I turn the browser flag off, dark document page colors show up perfectly fine, but I would really appreciate avoiding eye strain both on Google Docs, *and* in other websites.

Comment: I can’t like because I’m considered a Stack Overflow noob :(. Anyways, clearing cache didn’t work, and although page color is by design white, with the browser flag enabled the page would appear black and text white a few months back, before some update broke that desired/undesired functionality. In conclusion, fiddling with Dark Reader’s settings is nearly the best of both worlds (you can apply the extension’s effects to only Docs), so thank you for that!

Comment: You can also send feedback to the relevant team and make your suggestions, just press `shift + alt + i` to edit and send it.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I tried this feature, and I found that `#enable-force-dark` works normally in Chrome(verion 96.0.4664.45) and Edge(version 96.0.1054.43). In Google Docs, except for the document part, the background is dark, something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdOaW.png). So I think this is by design.

If this feature does not work correctly, you can try to reset Edge/Chrome or clear the cache, which may be useful to you.

In addition, I found an extension named [Dark Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh), I think it will suit you, you can set the level of background color according to your preference. It also works with the document part in Google Docs, and you can even switch back to the default background without restart the browser.